# Find all points $(a,b)$ for which all roots of $ax^2 + 2bx + 4a = 0$ are higher than 1.

Tags: graphing-functions

> Find all points $(a,b)$ for which all roots of $ax^2 + 2bx + 4a = 0$ are higher than 1.

I found out that roots are of form $\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4a^2}}{a}$ and $\frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2 - 4a^2}}{a}$, but I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: But how to solve them? There are 2 variables

Comment: Divide by a, as I do in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$ax^2 + 2bx + 4a = 0
$,
dividing by $a$
we get
$x^2+(2b/a)x = -4
$.

We can not have
$a=0$,
because this becomes
$2bx=0$
which root $0$
which is too small.

To simplify,
let $c = b/a$.
We then have
$x^2+2cx = -4
$.

Adding
$c^2$,
$-4+c^2
=x^2+2cx+c^2
=(x+c)^2
$
or
$x
=-c\pm\sqrt{-4+c^2}
$.

For this to have real roots,
then
$c^2 \ge 4$
or
$|c| \ge 2$.

If
$c \ge 0$,
then
$-c-\sqrt{-4+c^2}
< 0
$,
so one root is negative,
which is out.

Therefore,
we must have
$c < 0$.
Since we need
$|c| \ge 2$,
we must have
$c \le -2$.

Let $c = -d$,
so we are looking at
$d \pm \sqrt{d^2-4}$.
The smaller of these is
$d - \sqrt{d^2-4}$,
so we want
$d - \sqrt{d^2-4}> 1$,
or
$d-1 > \sqrt{d^2-4}
$.

Squaring,
since $d-1 > 1$,
$d^2-2d+1
> d^2-4
$
or
$2d < 5$
or
$d < \frac52$.

Therefore
$2 \le d < \frac52$
or
$-2 \ge c > -\frac52$.

Putting the definition of $c$,
this becomes
$-2 \ge \frac{b}{a} > -\frac52$.